# Painting QPixmap in the center of QTableView cell

Tags: qt, qtableview, qstyleditemdelegate

I have a QTableView that works very well, the first column holds some thumbnails, in each cell of this column the thumbnails are vertically centered, but not horizontally centered.

Do I really need to use a delegate?
If yes, How to center them horizontally using QStyledItemDelegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing by yourself is not necessary, but a custom delegate - is. The styled item delegate uses the style's control element drawing code to draw a `CE_ItemViewItem` - see [the source code for Qt 5.5.0](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/v5.5.0/src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp#L2176). The drawing code takes the style option's `decorationAlignment` member into account. Unfortunately, there's no data role that would pass that alignment to the styles's implementation. Instead, you have to override the alignment in your delegate:

```
class DecorationAligningDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
  Q_OBJECT
  Qt::Alignment const m_alignment;
public:
  explicit DecorationAligningDelegate(Qt::Alignment alignment, QObject * parent = 0) :
    QStyledItemDelegate(parent), m_alignment(alignment) {}
  Qt::Alignment alignment() const { return m_alignment; }
  void paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const {
    auto opt = option;
    opt.decorationAlignment = m_alignment;
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, opt, index);
  }
};
```

Then, to center the thumbnails:

```
view.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, 
  new DecorationAligningDelegate(Qt::AlignHCenter, &view));
//or
view->setItemDelegateForColumn(0, 
  new DecorationAligningDelegate(Qt::AlignHCenter, view));
```

If you really wished to paint it all yourself, even though it's unnecessary, the rectangle of the item to be painted is given in the style option (`option.rect`). To draw the pixmap centered in the item's rectangle, you could do as follows:

```
QStyleOption option;
QPixmap pix;
QPainter painter;
...
painter.save();
auto loc = option.rect.center() - pix.rect().center()
painter.drawPixmap(loc, pix);
painter.restore();
```

Comment: So, I have to use a delegate?

Comment: @MohamedAnwer Yes, you do, but the delegate is trivial and doesn't paint anything by itself. I've shown the complete source of a delegate that does such an alignment, and how to set it on your desired column. It's a simple workaround for an omission in Qt's view and style code.

Comment: I did exactly the first code snippet, and the vertical alignment has gone away, and still no horizontal alignment,
I changed Qt::AlignHCenter to (Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter), and the vertical alignment showed up again, but still not horizontal alignment, 
What do you think now?

Comment: @MohamedAnwer Either `QIcon::paint` is broken and ignores vertical alignment, or the view is "clever" and provides only enough vertical area to fit the icon, so that the alignment becomes a no-op. Add `qDebug() << option.rect` to the beginning of your delegate's `paint`. See if it's any bigger than the icon itself. If it is bigger, you'd have to debug into Qt's code and figure out what is the value of `iconRect` in [this line of code](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/v5.5.0/src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp#L2150). What's your Qt version?

Comment: I am using Qt 5.5,
the rect is bigger than the pixmap,
BTW, The rect width expands when I resize the widget width

Comment: @MohamedAnwer Then it seems that `QIcon::paint` is broken. Perhaps you should make a testcase to demonstrate that and file a Qt bug if it is so.

Comment: The second part of your answer is working just fine, The problem in my code was getting the pixmap from model, I had to do `index.data(Qt::DecorationRole)` not only `index.data()`, I adjusted it in the model to be produced only in `DecorationRole`, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Construct your own delegate and inherit QStyledItemDelegate. Override the paint method.

Then do something like this:

```
void
MyDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                            const QModelIndex& index) const
{

     QPixmap pixmap;
     pixmap.load("Your pixmap file path");
     pixmap = pixmap.scaled(option.rect.width(), option.rect.height(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    // Position our pixmap
    const int x = option.rect.center().x() - pixmap.rect().width() / 2;
    const int y = option.rect.center().y() - pixmap.rect().height() / 2;

    if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight());         
    }

    painter->drawPixmap(QRect(x, y, pixmap.rect().width(), pixmap.rect().height()), pixmap);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will just leave my version that literary is a combination of the two answers.

```
class DecorationAligningDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DecorationAligningDelegate(Qt::Alignment alignment, QObject *parent = nullptr)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent), m_alignment(alignment) {}

    Qt::Alignment alignment() const { return m_alignment; }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        QIcon icon = QIcon(qvariant_cast<QIcon>(index.data(Qt::DecorationRole)));

        if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
        {
             painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight());
        }

        icon.paint(painter, option.rect, m_alignment);
    }

private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(VDecorationAligningDelegate)
    Qt::Alignment const m_alignment;
};
```

I assume you define your item like this:

```
auto *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
item->setIcon(QIcon("Your pixmap file path"));
```

Don't forget about setting a delegate.